# Joomla + Hikashop version 2.6.3

Tags: php, joomla

short question I am using HikaShop version 2.6.3, I would like to move my price from top right position to bottom position. Does this plugin have configuration where I can set this or should this be fixed directly in file ?

Example: http://www.parrotmag.com/shop-subscribe/product/23795-issue-231-april-2017

At the moment price is on top and I would like to put it after description, meaning on bottom.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an template override for the layouts in the product category. They start from the show.php and from there other layouts are loaded